# Early 90s sci-fi show with a race of mutants

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

There was an early 90s SciFi show that played in the New York City area on public television. All I remember were there being like two races of people, one being normal human and the other were seemingly mutated people. I also remember there being really cool vehicles that the normal humans would ride out into the badlands where the mutant types lived, these vehicles had like 6 wheels and looked like military type vehicles.

(This has been bugging me for years, would really want to know the name of this show)

Comment: I don't have the name, but I remember a pilot that was never picked up that involved most of the earth's population being mutated by a disease into Neanderthal-type creatures with heavy brow ridges.  The unaffected humans had one captive in a glass enclosure who just stood around looking perplexed.  Also there was one member of the team who was "half mutant", with the heavy brow ridge, but normal mental function.  Does that sound like what you remember?

Comment: @WillFeldman Yes! That's the one, I remember that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be the unpicked pilot [Island City](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110163/combined) from 1994, where most of humanity mutates into violent primitive creatures (like Will has described) and the remaining healthy people fight them and migrate to the titular safeheaven. It features futuristic 8-wheeled vehicles roaming the desert areas populated by those mutants. The whole thing is [available here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKPSMCc0_WI) (it starts around 9:30).

Comment: Yes!! Thank you, this is exactly it. Thank you so much, its literally been bugging me for years. The YouTube link says that it was shown repeatedly during a summer, why would a pilot be repeatedly shown on TV? I thought pilots were usually shown, well once. (FWIW, it definitely won the 6 year old crowd).

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian It was a movie pilot which means it can and usually will be shown many times.